# "das" or "die" after sind

Tags: word-usage, difference, grammatical-number

In the following sentence:

> Wie sind ___ Lebensmittel auf den Philippinen? / Sie sind so teuer.

Which one should I use in the blank position? The book states that **das** is used, but why can't we use **die** instead?

a) Wie sind die Lebensmittel (plural) auf den Philippinen?
b) Wie sind das Lebensmittel auf den Philippinen?

Which one to use and why?

Comment: Sind is already plural, is it not,

Comment: Are you sure you quote the sentence in its entirety and also the solution suggestions correctly?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Yes, it is supposed to be plural.

Comment: @planetmaker Yes, I took this from the book "Toms Deutschseite". I believe that the answer key is written wrongly for this question. I think "die" is supposed to fill the blank place in the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: The example sentence has its weaknesses. 1) *Wie sind* in no way indicates, what is asked for: tastefulness, availability, … 2) Philippinen looks weird without an article. So I‘m not sure, whether something can be learned from it.

Comment: "Wie sind die Lebensmittel auf den Philippinen?" sounds like a reasonable sentence if you want to ask "How is food on the philippines?"

Comment: @planetmaker: I was wondering about *in* vs. *auf* here since the Philippines is an archipelago. In English it would be "in" instead of "on": "in Iceland", "in Ireland", "in Sicily", but my understanding was German tends to use *auf* for islands.

Comment: Yes indeed. 'auf' when you think island, 'in' when you think country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to write it explicitly your book seems to be incorrect on that one and you're intuition is right, it's plural indicated by the "sind" and the article needs to be "die".

Even if "Lebensmittel" wouldn't refer to a life essential product, but rather to an average like the sweet little German words "durchschnittliche Lebenshaltungskosten" it would still require an "ist" for "das" to make sense. Also no one would say that.

Comment: Das durchschnittliche Lebenshaltungskosten?

Comment: Nope "die durchschnittlichen Lebenshaltungskosten" aber "das Lebensmittel" if there were a colloquial usage of that word in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Wie sind die Lebensmittel in den Philippinen? Sie sind so teuer.

A better question would be:

> Wie sind die Lebensmittelpreise in den Philippinen? (also possible: auf den Philippinen)

Oder:

> Wie teuer sind die Lebensmittel in den Philippinen?

We use *die* Lebensmittel because we refer here to the plural, more than just one Lebensmittel, for example we think here about the prices for bread, milk, meat ...

An example for using *das*: Wasser ist das Lebensmittel Nummer 1. Here we refer to one Lebensmittel only (Wasser).
In any case 'ist' means singular and 'sind' plural.